# How to put legend graphic representation to the right of the label

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, legend

All the `pgfplots` examples I could find have the graphic (e.g. symbol) to the left of the label (see example below) in the legend. I think this default is very good but due to space constrains I have to switch the order (together with the options `legend cell align=right`).

**How do I put the legend graphic representation to the *right* of the label?**

Here it is a typical example with graphics on the *left* (`--*-- Case 1`), but I want `Case 1 --*--`.

[image: totheleft]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need at least to specify the `legend plot pos` key for `axis` environment. It is described in Section 4.8.5 of the package manual.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      legend plot pos=right
    ]
      \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] coordinates {
        (0,2)
        (2,3)
        (3,1)
      };
      \addlegendentry{Case 1}
      \addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (0,0)
        (1,1)
        (2,1)
        (3,2)
      };
      \addlegendentry{Case 2}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For other possible customizations have a look at the »[pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)« manual.

---

[image]

Comment: I overlooked that option by confusing it with `legend pos`, thanks!